# Changing attribute type from String to Double in Core Data and Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm trying to do this and I haven't found any clear documentation on it. I can't do a lightweight migration and apparently I have to make a mapping model but nowhere shows how to do this. I know you create a mapping model and select the old data model as source and the new one as destination, but what then? There is very little information on heavy migration and almost none with Swift.

Comment: https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-migration/

Comment: This is Objective-C but I'll try and translate it. In 'Progressive Migrations' where does this code even go? Also, I've created a mapping model and NSEntityMigrationPolicy class with the right method in it, but this does nothing. How do I make sure the mapping model is used?

Comment: There is a example project just before that method on BookMigration. Just follow the example project.

Comment: @New16 I can't find in that project where you select that the mapping models are used. For example, I've found no reference in that example project to 'Model1_to_Model2.xcmappingmodel'

Comment: The mapping model is used programatically. It is not hardcoded thats it. There are getting it `[NSMappingModel mappingModelFromBundles:@[[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                                           forSourceModel:sourceModel
                                         destinationModel:model]` using this method.

Comment: @New16 I don't understand you. That code is in `NSMappingModel.h` but I don't see what difference it makes. Can you answer this: after I subclass `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` and override `createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance`, what is the next step?